# Deleting duplicate record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I have written a query to remove duplicate records from a table

```
;WITH a as
(
SELECT Firstname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Firstname, empID ORDER BY Firstname) 
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM dbo.tblEmployee
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM tblEmployee
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```

But I don't know where I went wrong it is saying

> Invalid column name `duplicateRecCount`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to reference the CTE in the delete statement...

```
WITH a as
(
SELECT Firstname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Firstname, empID ORDER BY Firstname) 
AS duplicateRecCount
FROM dbo.tblEmployee
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
DELETE FROM a
WHERE duplicateRecCount > 1
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 DELETE duplicates FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname, EMPNO, salary,dept  ORDER BY empno) cnt
 FROM tblEmp)  duplicates
WHERE duplicates.Cnt > 1
```