# In SSIS Data Flow, is there a better way to make distinct rows for all columns than "Sort"?

Tags: ssis

**In SSIS Data Flow, is there a better way to make distinct rows for all columns than "Sort"?**

***Below are details, but the essence of what I'm asking is whether there is a better way to make my set distinct after I union the four Flat Files.***

I have an SSIS project where I read four different tab-delimited text files, union them, and insert them into a database table. I have been led to believe that "Sort" is the only way to make the rows distinct before I insert them into the database table.

In an ideal world, I would be dealing with unique rows, but the reality is that I don't have unique rows, and I cannot clean up the source data before it gets to me.

While my project works, I am convinced there must be a better way to do this -- and by better, I mean not only in terms of performance, but also better in the sense that it is simpler and more direct for me to set up in SSIS.

The examples of "Sort" I see on the web selects only a few columns of a much larger table, and the option "Remove rows with duplicate sort values" -- if taken literally -- would only check for duplication in those selected columns.  So to make sure I'm not missing anything, I sort by *all* columns. Unfortunately, I don't need any of my columns sorted -- I handle that on the client side. So, there is a performance hit.

To give you a sense of scale, here's a screenshot while I'm in debug mode. No errors, so at least I've gotten that far.

Thank you for any ideas.

[image: SSIS Diagram of Data Flow in Debug Mode]

And here's a screenshot of the "Sort" box so you can see the number of columns involved and how I am currently making my set distinct before insertion into the Database table.

[image: Sort to Make Distinct]

Comment: Are the rows truly, entirely, 100% identical? Like a straight string comparison would reveal them to be the same?

Comment: And if there are duplicates, it doesn't matter which file's row gets inserted, right?

Comment: Yes. When two or more rows are duplicate, they are duplicate in _all_ columns.  It's the reality I have to work with.  I'm not choosing a particular row to insert over the other: I just want to make the rows distinct, as we do when we query a table with "Select distinct * from ...".

Comment: Can you just delete duplicates in your destination database?

Comment: For the sake of conversation, let's say that I'm trying to avoid that. I need to focus my efforts in the scope and location of the stated question. There's a lot of back story that I'm not including because I don't want to introduce any red herrings into the mix.

Comment: Rather than modify the source files, could you, say, "clean them up" in a process and write the results to new files, and then use THOSE files in this task? (The "clean up" thing could be in SSIS, if that's a requirement.)

Comment: That's a possibility, if I could send the union to a temp table, select distinct * from the temp table, and _then_ insert into the database table, that would work. Now it's a matter of me learning how to create a temp table in SSIS and select distinct from that...

Comment: The equivalent of a temp table in SSIS is the Recordset Destination, which you can then shred in .Net with a Script Task like a dataTable.

Comment: Something you said indirectly inspired another approach I could use.  On the Control Flow tab, I start off with an "Execute SQL Task" that clears the destination table before starting the "Data Flow Task".  Could then make that Task point to following SQL Task that runs a T-SQL script to load the existing table into a temp table. I could then clear that table and then insert a fresh select distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that I hadn't considered when I asked the question: on the "Control Flow" tab, after the Data Flow tasks are done, start a SQL Task that reads the table into a temp table, clears the table, and then inserts only unique rows.

This approach doesn't waste time sorting the data. It also makes me sure that I'm getting truly distinct rows in the way I expect them to be.  It's probably not *the* best way and no doubt is making a few people cringe, but it is an approach that I am able to implement with my current skill set.  All because Microsoft didn't put a "Distinct union" option in the Data Flow taskbar.

[image: Screenshot of Control Flow tab]

**Update:** 
By Kyle Hale's suggestion, I improved the T-SQL query (identify and remove specific duplicates), which eliminates the need for a temp table.

```
WITH Dup_Rows (
    Rec_Nbr,
    Campus,
    Student_ID,
    Student_Name,
    Course_ID,
    Course_Title,
    Credit,
    Date_Earned,
    Department,
    Final_Mark,
    Grade_Level,
    School,
    Teacher,
    [Transfer]
    )
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY c.Campus,
            c.Student_ID,
            c.Student_Name,
            c.Course_ID,
            c.Course_Title,
            c.Credit,
            c.Date_Earned,
            c.Department,
            c.Final_Mark,
            c.Grade_Level,
            c.School,
            c.Teacher,
            c.[Transfer] ORDER BY c.Campus,
                c.Student_ID,
                c.Student_Name,
                c.Course_ID,
                c.Course_Title,
                c.Credit,
                c.Date_Earned,
                c.Department,
                c.Final_Mark,
                c.Grade_Level,
                c.School,
                c.Teacher,
                c.[Transfer]
            ) AS Rec_Nbr,
        c.Campus,
        c.Student_ID,
        c.Student_Name,
        c.Course_ID,
        c.Course_Title,
        c.Credit,
        c.Date_Earned,
        c.Department,
        c.Final_Mark,
        c.Grade_Level,
        c.School,
        c.Teacher,
        c.[Transfer]
    FROM dbo.Base__credits c
    )
DELETE
FROM Dup_Rows
WHERE Dup_Rows.Rec_Nbr > 1
```

Comment: So you decided to delete duplicates in the destination table after all? A perfectly valid solution.

Comment: But if you're inserting into SQL Server 2005 or later, you don't need to create a temp table to delete duplicates. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053693/deleting-duplicate-record-in-sql-server

Comment: Yep. I was able to make the paradigm shift and do the deletions within SSIS. When you first suggested it, I perceived it as a suggestion to delete from the table outside of SSIS (like a scheduled job in SQL Agent).

Comment: Also, in order to perform a "distinct union" SSIS would still need to do a (blocking) sorting/hashing mechanism on all rows in the union since it won't know until the very last record is read that it has found every possible duplicate. Since SSIS works on a buffering strategy, this is less than ideal. Better to shred the data into a common place and then perform the one-time set operation there.

Comment: In regards to your second comment, that's a good idea I didn't think of. That should take out an unnecessary step. Thanks.

Comment: The website you cited definitely helped make my query more efficient and shaved some seconds off the total time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Aggregate Task within the data flow. It doesn't sort, just groups by or sums, averages, etc, which from your comments is what you're looking for.

NOTE: There will be a performance hit regardless of the method you choose, but this will do a distinct rather than a sort.

Comment: I took a look at Aggregate, but I do not want to do any aggregate calculations (like sum, avg, etc.). I simply want a distinct set without any duplicate rows. That's why I did not pursue this path.

Comment: You don't need to use sum avg etc. It is simply doing the same thing as an SQL Group By or Distinct.

Comment: I think thats the only viable solution that does not introduce any overhead like (duplicate read/write of data, additional tasks, ...) and it will also be faster than the SORT task

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is "identify and remove duplicates before it reaches the destination", you can see how this can only be accomplished by use of some sort of temporary holding structure, since SSIS has to pull in every single value of the files to know if any given row is a duplicate.

My personal suggestion would be to write a Script Task to remove duplicates **at a row level** from your files.

1. Create a Script Task called "Clean TSV Files".
2. Create an array in your script called Checksums.
3. In your script, open each TSV file and read through it in a loop, one line at a time.
4. Call String.GetHashCode() on the row.
5. If the value is in Checksums, toss out the row, it's a dupe.
6. If not, store the resulting value in Checksums, and pass the row to some other File object.
7. Save the new File object somewhere SSIS can see.

Now you'll have 4 files that have been cleaned and are ready to just be unioned and inserted into your database.

If for whatever reason you don't want to do file modification and want to keep everything in memory, you could also write the results to a Recordset Destination and then use that as an ADO object in a Script Source, but that is potentially memory intensive.

Comment: The key is that I need to make them distinct _after_ I union them, because the same row might be present in more than one table.

Comment: This solves that problem, once a row has been "checked" and passed on, any other row that matches it will be discarded from any file, since its checksum is in the array.

Comment: Once this script is run, your files will contain no duplicates in any of the files, since each unique row instance was only propagated once to the modified files / Recordset.

Comment: The technique presented is new to me, so I'll need to learn how to do some of the items.  Thanks for your suggestion. I'll let you know a little later today how it works.

Comment: After looking into "Script Task" I see that the learning curve is a little to steep for the moment. So while I trust that this is _a_ solution, at the moment it is not the best solution _for me_ because of my current skill gaps.  I posted my Plan B as a separate answer, although I don't think I'll mark that one as my answer either. I still have an open mind for other alternatives.