# remove duplicate relations in self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to self join one table on the criteria that id should not be same but market should be same in this way 
 i found relating market for diffrent ids but in doing so i got dupl;icate relations like 1-3 and 3-1 b ut i do not need both entries 
 i only need first one 1-3 there are million of rows in table so please help me optimizing this query too.

```
 declare @tbl table (id int   , market varchar(100))

 insert into @tbl (id,market)
 values(1,'abc'),(2,'xyz'),(3,'abc')

 select a.id , a.market , b.id ,b.market 
 from  @tbl a join  @tbl b 
 on a.id <> b.id 
 and a.market = b.market
```

Comment: Possbile duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053693/deleting-duplicate-record-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

Clean and simple

```
select abc.id, abc.market , xyz.id , xyz.market
from  @tbl abc join  @tbl xyz
on abc.id <> xyz.id and abc.market = xyz.market and abc.id < xyz.id
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a9e7/3)

Comment: consider id columns as varchar column there could be alphanumeric id's.

Comment: You should have the primary key on the table right? You should use that in the `<` comparison.

Comment: I understand your point and it is working.One more help if you could do to optmize this query because i am executing this query on very large data set and it is taking lot more time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
select a.id , b.id , a.market
from  @tbl a join  @tbl b 
on a.id <> b.id and a.market = b.market and a.id < b.id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am taking id as sample , there could be varchar column instead of id numeric.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: It will consider `id` as alphanumeric. First use `subquery` to return the set of duplicate `market` with not equal `IDs` then join as you have done in your example

```
SELECT t.id, t.market, t1.id, t1.market
FROM(
    SELECT market, MIN(id) id
    FROM @tbl
    GROUP BY market HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1) t
INNER JOIN @tbl t1 ON t1.market = t.market
    AND t1.id <> t.id
```