# Delete duplicate rows with an order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

[image: table DAILYDATAWH]

I want to delete duplicate rows in that table based on different `STATUSIN` 
and this is my query to duplicate rows:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID,NIP, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY STATUSIN ORDER BY STATUSIN) AS RowNumber
   FROM DAILYDATAWH
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT TOP (1000) * 
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE2 WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

and this is the output:

[image: delete duplicate rows]

how to delete duplicate rows and show the output like this:

[image: output]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, instead format it as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting duplicate record in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053693/deleting-duplicate-record-in-sql-server)

Comment: try changing the order by in RowNumber ?

Comment: i think i've been try that query, but it doesn't show the output that i want @KarlAnka

Comment: can you write an example code to explain that? because, i've been try change the value in order by @Lemon

Comment: ORDER BY STATUSIN desc) AS RowNumber?

Comment: ID, i guess is a primary key and you want to rearrange records in your main table, it is not possible. If you just want to show records like in the below picture, then after deleting the records, use 
 select * from DAILYDATAWH order by NIP,NAME,StatusIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed ID in the partition Order by. This produces what you want as you are always deleting the 2nd , 3rd .. duplicate. Anchor your query on the first instance as below.

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY STATUSIN ORDER BY ID, STATUSIN) AS RowNumber,
ID, NIP, Name,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT FROM #DAILYDATAWH
```

I would also mention that you should probably strengthen how you are partitioning. What happens if you get multiple customer records with the exact same time stamp? EG is NIP + Name unique? Added name to the below example.

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name,STATUSIN ORDER BY Name, STATUSIN) AS RowNumber,
ID, NIP, Name,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT FROM #DAILYDATAWH
```

Solution for your query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY STATUSIN ORDER BY ID, STATUSIN) AS RowNumber
,
ID, NIP, Name,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT FROM #DAILYDATAWH
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT TOP (1000) * 
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE2 WHERE RowNumber > 1

    SELECT * FROM #DAILYDATAWH
```

Answer (score 2):

In your particular scenario logic which has been written will not work work because if you closely look at the output of your CTE you will always have RowNumber as 1.

You query would be somewhat like this.

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
(
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,NIP        VARCHAR(2)
    ,[NAME]     VARCHAR(10)
    ,DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(4)
    ,STATUSIN   DATETIME
)

INsERT INTO @Temp
(
     NIP
    ,[NAME]
    ,DEPARTMENT
    ,STATUSIN
)
VALUES
 ('A1','ARIA','BB',GETDATE())
,('A1','ARIA','BB',GETDATE())
,('A1','ARIA','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE()))
,('A1','ARIA','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,GETDATE()))
,('A2','CHLOE','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-2,GETDATE()))
,('A2','CHLOE','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-3,GETDATE()))
,('A2','CHLOE','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-3,GETDATE()))
,('A3','Test','BB',DATEADD(MINUTE,-6,GETDATE()))

;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
         NIP
        ,[NAME]
        ,ID         = MAX(Id)
        ,STATUSIN
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY STATUSIN) AS RowNumber
   FROM @Temp
   GROUP BY
        NIP
        ,[NAME]     
        ,STATUSIN
)
SELECT * -- To do a delete change this line to DELETE T 
FROM 
    @Temp AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE ON T.ID = CTE.ID
WHERE
    CTE.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    T.[NAME]
    ,T.STATUSIN
```

I have only written select which will display the records needs to be deleted. You can verify the results by changing CTE.ID IS NULL to IS NOT NULL.

I hope this will help... Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for helping me, it's work. Can you write that with delete function?

Comment: I have added instructions to do a delete... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. ID, i guess is a primary key and if you want to rearrange records in your main table, it is not possible because it is stored in ascending order.
2. If you just want to show records like in the below picture, then after deleting the records, use

```
select * from DAILYDATAWH order by NIP,NAME,StatusIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes:

`PARTITION BY STATUSIN ORDER BY STATUSIN`

Having the same columns in the partition by and order by makes no sense. You say:

> I want to delete duplicate rows in that table based on different
>   STATUSIN

Good, you have defined what the `ORDER BY` should be. This decides which row to keep among duplicates.

The `PARTITION BY` part must includes the columns that define which columns are duplicate. A guess would be `NIP,NAME`, but you have to decide for yourself. So try something like this:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NIP,NAME ORDER BY STATUSIN) AS RowNumber`

The rest of the code seems ok to me.

Comment: I've been decide the columns are duplicate, that is `NIP,NAME,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT`. and i've been changed the query into thhis : `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NIP,NAME,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT ORDER BY STATUSIN) AS RowNumber` but the result still same like before